# Return to the main thread after the threadpool shuts down?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, program-entry-point

I have a Thread pool with 5 threads and have their future handles stored in an ArrayList. What I want to do is return to the main thread after all the threads exit. My situation is to create a program which runs infinitely. My concept is simple but I am not sure how to implement it.

1. `main()` method calls a `threadManager()` method
2. `threadManager()` creates threads
3. Some thread throws an exception and issues `futureCancel()` method which issues `future.cancel` for all the threads, and then shuts down the thread pool
4. The program returns to the main method which again calls the `threadManager()` and goes on.

Comment: Could you rename `futureCancel` (to something like `restartThreads`) and build in a call to `threadManager` at the end of it? (You could potentially fire up a new thread to run `threadManager` if the error handling thread isn't a good place to be running it.) It sounds to me like at the end of the day, you want to close down everything on this error and start it all back up. `main` isn't special; you could do that in any method on any thread. One note: I would make sure that some clean way of shutting down the application exists.

Comment: You got my point, at the end of an error, I was to close everything and restart it. i think i can just make futureCancel (restarThread) a new thread outside of the old pool which shuts down the old and pool and restarts a new one.

Comment: I have a shutdown hook which I use for any catastrophic event which cleans up all my network connections before an improper shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
// Always has 5 threads even if 1 throws an exception
ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
while(results.isEmpty()) {
    List<Callable<T>> tasks = createTasks();
    List<Future<T>> futures = exe.invokeAll(tasks);

    for(Future<T> future : futures) {
        try{
            results.add(future.get()); // throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
        } catch(Exception e) {
            results.clear();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something similar. But i do not store the results. So I am using an external library which helps in detecting timeout over the connection which my threads create. Once I get a timeout on one connection, I go and issue "future.cancel" for the rest. Is there a way I can return to the main thread after that method? Adding a while(true) loop is an option but I wanted something else which stays blocked on an action or something like that.

Comment: I don't understand your concept of "return to" the main thread. The main thread never stops running. Threads don't "go to" and "come back from" each other. They are created, they run, sometimes they stop. They don't "visit" each other.